# ASP.Net Membership Change Password method does not show up

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

I have implemented a Custom Membership provider. A sample of my code is shown below

```
public class CustomMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
{
   public override bool ChangePassword(string username, string oldPassword, string newPassword)
   {
      //logic for changing password
   }

   public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
   {
      //logic for validating user credentials
   }
}
```

I then registered the above Custom Membership in the `web.config` file by using

```
<membership defaultProvider="CustomMembershipProvider">
 <providers>
  <clear/>
   <add name ="CustomMembershipProvider" type="MyApplication.CustomMembershipProvider"/>
 </providers>
</membership>
```

Now, when I want to authenticate a user, I can call

```
System.Web.Security.Membership.ValidateUser(username, password);
```

This works. However, when I want to call the method to change the password, I try calling:

```
System.Web.Security.Membership.ChangePassword(username, oldPassword, newPassword);
```

It gives me intellisense and compilation errors saying that `System.Web.Security.Membership` does not contain the definition for `ChangePassword`.

How do I link my `ChangePassword` method to be callable from `System.Web.Security.Membership` or am I approaching this problem in the wrong way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your Membership provider is well defined:

```
<membership defaultProvider="CustomMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add connectionStringName="ConnString" enablePasswordReset="true" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" name="CustomMembershipProvider" type="MyMembershipProvider" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

I take it that `MyApplication.MyMembershipProvider` is your custom Membership class. I would rename to something else to make the `web.config` easier to read later, so you know what is the class when you see it.

However, what I believe the answer to your problem is, **you need to tap into the Provider class within Membership**. Since your defined a Custom Provider, you will use this to execute some of your custom changes.

```
var didChange = System.Web.Security.Membership.Provider.ChangePassword("", "", "");
```

Comment: The error from Visual Studio is 'System.Web.Security.Membership' does not contain a definition for 'ChangePassword'

Comment: no luck. I tried your web.config change along with a rebuild of the entire solution but it still doesnt show up.

Comment: Sorry, I jumped the gun to soon on the update! I didn't realize part of my answer didn't post.

Comment: The part of your answer in bold fixed my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If any of the parameter is null in WebSecurity.ChangePassword, it will not call Custom Memembership provider Change Password